# Swing freezes when app system tray right clicked (shown)

Tags: java, swing

When right click on the application tray icon (triggering show tray popup menu) swing application freezes. Found old answers (2008) that it is because some native methods is called by java to show it. Is there any way to solve/workaround that?

Quick SECode below:

```
package test;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestApp {
    private static JFrame mainFrame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            start();
        }
    });
}

private static void start() {
    initApp();

    SystemTray systemTray;
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu();
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\test\\image.png").getImage(), "test", popupMenu);


    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        initializePopupMenu(popupMenu);
        try {
            systemTray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            //                      throw new TrayNotSupportedException("Tray is not supported.");
        }
    }
}

private static void initializePopupMenu(PopupMenu popupMenu) {
    popupMenu.add(new MenuItem("test Item"));
}

private static void initApp() {
    JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(progress);
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: I've not had (or seen anybody else with) this issue, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: My problem is similar to one reported here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1289240?tstart=0 ... I'm preparing right now self exp. code ...will post soon

Comment: ok posted a code. See that progress is freezed when tray item is shown.

Comment: @MadProgrammer same happens when i modify Oracle's demo application from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html